# how to edit the Dojo Grid Data

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, dojo.gridx

How can I edit the grid Data from the Grid table directly to Database with dojo. I cannot change the data to DB Directly with this.

I'm Following the Tutorial from dojo site it self where it says use "editable = true" but when i double click it and change the data, how data will be changed in database.

I'm Using this line

```
{name: "Auto Pass", field:"autopass",width:"100px",type: dojox.grid.cells.Bool, editable: true}
```

But this does not change data in db is their any function that I need to call?

Comment: I don't think grid can update your DB directly. The store that you created could have come from anywhere like from a json file or from an external source. So your grid will not have any idea that where it came from. Post edit, you have to write a code to update DB.

Comment: Yup this was the issue i had figured! BTW Thanks